# What is the origin of executable compression?

Tags: compression, executables

According to the [wikipedia article on the topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_compression), the earliest executable compressor listed is Realia Spacemaker for IBM PC (*since 1982, written by [Robert B. K. Dewar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_B._K._Dewar), SM.COM, signature "MEMORY$"*).

One of the pages referred by the wiki entry claims that the distinction of being the first executable compressor [almost certainly belongs to Realia SpaceMaker](http://www.os2museum.com/wp/realia-spacemaker/). It could as well be, given that *SpaceMaker compresses runs of repeated zero bytes—but only zero bytes* (I cannot think of anything more basic than that), but is that actually true?

Was there an earlier executable compressor tool advertised as such on any pre-IBM PC computer?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122791/discussion-on-question-by-leo-b-what-is-the-origin-of-executable-compression).